# How to setup a secure code evaluator in LearnR like rstudio.cloud does?

Tags: r, r-markdown, learnr

When we use the  self-hosted version of Learn R or hosted version in  shinyapps.io, the user can print out variables that contain the tutorial source code using the code evaluator.

For example in  [shinyapps](https://learnr-examples.shinyapps.io/ex-data-filter/#section-filter-rows-with-filter) hosted version, the user can run `.server_context` to get the source code of the current rmd:

[image]

**(UPDATED) Example 2:**

By running `cat(system("cat /srv/connect/apps/ex-data-filter/ex-data-filter.Rmd", intern = TRUE), sep = '\n')` can to get the source code of the current rmd too:
[image]

But interestingly in [rstudio.cloud](https://rstudio.cloud/learn/primers/3.4) hosted version, the code evaluator seems to be sandboxed, and all "sensitive" variables cannot be run through the evaluator.

[image]

Can I get some advice on how to implement such a secure code evaluator?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you may have accidentally uploaded the same picture twice.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I’ve fixed the issue in the latest version of learnr available on GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/learnr

Comment: Hey @grrrck, thanks for the effort! But still in https://learnr-examples.shinyapps.io/ex-data-filter/#section-filter-rows-with-filter by runnng`cat(system("cat /srv/connect/apps/ex-data-filter/ex-data-filter.Rmd", intern = TRUE), sep = '\n')` can list the source code of the Rmd, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Would you mind taking this conversation to the learnr discussion board? https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/discussions